# Find linear transformation isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to figure out if $\ T: \mathbb R_3[x] \rightarrow \mathbb R^{3}$ in which
$$\ T(x^2+2x) = (1,2,1) , \ T(x+1)=(0,1,1) , \ T(x^2-2)=(1,0,-1)$$ is an isomorphism.

I understand that in order for $T$ to be isomorphism $Ker(T) = \{0\} $

The set $\{x^2+2x;x+1;x^2-2\}$ is linearly dependent and I can't just determine $T$ of a basis of vectors of $\ \mathbb R_3[x] $. I'm not sure how to determine if $T(v) = 0 $ only if $v=0 $

Comment: Try finding $T(x^2)$, $T(x)$, $T(1)$ using linearity

Comment: Remember that you can choose images of elements of a basis freely. So can you A) extended $\{x+1,x^2-2\}$ to a basis of $\Bbb{R}_3[x]$, and B) choose an image for the third basis vector in such a way that $T$ becomes an isomorphism?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I can't find T(1). $\ T(1) = \alpha_1 T(v1) + \alpha_2 T(v2) + \alpha_3 T(v3) $ and then $\ (1,0,0) = \alpha_1 (0,2,1) + \alpha_2 (1,1,0) + \alpha_3 (-2,0,1) $ which can't be solved.

Comment: But how do I figure the image of the third basis that I chose?

Comment: @YardenGur It suffices to complete the given basis, for example by $x^2+2x, x+1$ adding a third linearly independent vector that is $x^2$ or $x^2+1$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you noted we don't have sufficient information to define $T$ indeed the vectors $x^2+2x,x+1, x^2-2$ are linearly dependent since

$$(x^2-2)+2(x+1)=x^2+2x$$

Of course we can find infinitely many isomorphism, extending the given basis, such that the condition given are fulfilled but $T$ can't be determined uniquely form the given information.

For example we can set

$$\ T(x^2+2x) = (1,2,1) , \ T(x+1)=(0,1,1) , \ T(x^2)=(0,0,1)$$

and in this case $T$ is an isomorphism which satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: Thanks! but could you explain to me how did you figure that $\ T(x^2) = (0,0,1) $ ?

Comment: @YardenGur We can choose arbitrarly a third linerly independent vectors as argument for $T$ (that is $x^2$) and send it to a third linearly independent vector $T(x^2)=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @YardenGur This way corresponds to the suggestion given also by Jyrki Lahtonen in the comment.

Comment: Ok so If I understand you correctly, we dont' know what T actually do and we also can't figure it out. So you just choose any vector that will complete the other two to a basis for R3 and then just choose any value we want for the image of this vector as long as all three image vectors are also linearly independent so the transformation will be isomorphism ?

Comment: @YardenGur Yes exactly we can't determine $T$ from the given information but we can complete the bases and define $T$ arbitrarly.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right), X_2 = (x^2, x, 1)^{\top}, B = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
$$

we have

$$
T\left(A X\right) = B X
$$

but $A$ has not maximum rank because $\det(A) = 0$ as the second row times $-2$ added to the first row gives the third row.

hence $T$ is not an isomorphism, because $T:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ because $B$ has maximum rank, and then $T$ is not bijective.

Comment: $T$ is not properly defined from the given information

Comment: If $T$ is linear which I assumed, it is conveniently defined.

Comment: Note that $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: Yes. You are right! I inverted $B$ instead $A$. I will change my answer accordingly. Thanks.